# image download problem (python)

Tags: python, multithreading

I was trying to download images with multi-thread, which has a limited max_count in python.

Each time a download_thread is started, I leave it alone and activate another one. I hope the download process could be ended in 5s, which means downloading is failed if opening the url costs more than 5s.

But how can I know it and stop the failed thread???

Comment: You broke the formatting after I fixed it. Code is denoted by indenting four spaces (using the `101010` button or Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you tell which version of python you are using?
Maybe you could have posted a snippet too.
From Python 2.6, you have a timeout added in urllib2.urlopen.
Hope this will help you. It's from the python docs.

> **urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][,
>   timeout])** Open the URL url, which can
>   be either a string or a Request
>   object.
>
> Warning HTTPS requests do not do any
>   verification of the server’s
>   certificate. data may be a string
>   specifying additional data to send to
>   the server, or None if no such data is
>   needed. Currently HTTP requests are
>   the only ones that use data; the HTTP
>   request will be a POST instead of a
>   GET when the data parameter is
>   provided. data should be a buffer in
>   the standard
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   format. The urllib.urlencode()
>   function takes a mapping or sequence
>   of 2-tuples and returns a string in
>   this format. urllib2 module sends
>   HTTP/1.1 requests with
>   Connection:close header included.
>
> *The optional timeout parameter
>   specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the
>   connection attempt (if not specified,
>   the global default timeout setting
>   will be used). This actually only
>   works for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP
>   connections.*
>
> This function returns a file-like
>   object with two additional methods:
>
> geturl() — return the URL of the
>   resource retrieved, commonly used to
>   determine if a redirect was followed
>   info() — return the meta-information
>   of the page, such as headers, in the
>   form of an mimetools.Message instance
>   (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)
>   Raises URLError on errors.
>
> Note that None may be returned if no
>   handler handles the request (though
>   the default installed global
>   OpenerDirector uses UnknownHandler to
>   ensure this never happens).
>
> In addition, default installed
>   ProxyHandler makes sure the requests
>   are handled through the proxy when
>   they are set.
>
> Changed in version 2.6: timeout was
>   added.

Comment: I tried to use timeout and get the result I want. By the way, it's so simple but I'm so grateful.

Comment: It sure is..Python makes programming fun.. ;)